# Rails engine overriding application's route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

We have an application and we outsourced an engine/gem named `Arcop`.  The engine creates surveys for clients and has a mailer which sends out emails with a link to the survey.  If the client is logged in to the application the link works correctly.  However, if the user is not logged in the application should redirect to the application's `sessions#new`.  What seems to be happening is that Rails is trying to find the route in the engine and not the application.

The error I'm getting when I click on the email link to go to the engine generated survey (/localhost:3001/arcop/survey_responses/30) is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions", :id=>"30"}
```

**application's application_controller.rb**

```
before_action :redirect_if_site_is_private

def redirect_if_site_is_private
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      save_location
      redirect_to login_path
    end
end
```

login path is defined as:

```
get 'sign-in' => 'sessions#new', as: :login
```

I read through the [Getting Started with Engines Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) and the engine inherits from ApplicationController properly:

```
class Arcop::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to override method `redirect_if_site_is_private` inside the engine's application_controller.rb with qualifier `main_app`.

```
def redirect_if_site_is_private
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      save_location
      redirect_to main_app.login_path
    end
  end
end
```